# Storing DeviceOrientationEvent and DeviceMotionEvent permissions across pages

Tags: javascript, permissions

I've got a nice DeviceMotionEvent request all working for Safari (or other browsers that require the permission), something along these lines:

```
// on click of a button
DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
.then(response => {
    if (response == 'granted') {
        // do my thing
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    // do my other thing
});
```

And thats working great. But when a user goes to a new page, they have to request the permission again. Obviously I'm calling 'requestPermission' again, so of course they would do.

How do I find out if permission has already been granted? Or is permission granted on a page by page basis (rather than session / site basis)?

I could store the response in localstorage or something, but would prefer something along the lines of:

```
DeviceMotionEvent.permissionStatus
```

Or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only option is to build a single page application and use the `history.pushState()` to update the location in the browser, when you wish to ‘change pages’.

Comment: So I guess in a non-SPA the answer would be no. Thats a shame ....

Comment: Yeah it looks that way

Comment: Saying that could you put you app in a full page iFrame and then send the data from the parent page into the iFrame, which would be free to load new pages?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** 
You can use the [`Web Storage API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) with the following two mechanisms:

- `sessionStorage`
- `localStorage`

As the names imply, these two interfaces are ideal for session-based data or if you want to persist state even after the connection is closed.

Comment: Im not sure this answers the question? Ive got a 'classic' web app (if you will), where users navigate to new pages on the site. They have to request and confirm everytime that the site wants access to DeviceMotionEvent. Its not about new tabs / windows and checking blur events (visibilitychange)

Comment: I have misinterpreted the term page as web page, as opposed to app page but the concept is the same. I do not think you necessarily need an SPA to push state changes every time the user is on a different page. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check whether permissions have been granted using the devicemotion eventListener. Baring in mind you have to push a button or similar to run DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()

eg.

```
let hasOrientationControls = false;
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", () => {
    hasOrientationControls = true;
});


// then when the button is pressed we can request permissions if we need
onButtonPressed () => {
   if (hasOrientationControls) return;
   else DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission();
}
```

I've also used this

```
isVRReady = window.DeviceOrientationEvent && "ontouchstart" in window;
```